# android how do i construct a list view that dynamically generates radio buttons

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

My main goal is to construct a ListView which places groups of three radio buttons. At the bottom of the screen. I have a button called Next. When I click next I want all the radio buttons that are clicked on saved. Could anyone advise me that best way to go about this.

e.g.

- Question
- The answers are grouped.
- Answer
- Answer2
- Anser 3

Then this is repeat. I have the data in a cursor and was hoping that i could output the particular records. But I am not sure how to dynamically generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not perfect in this. However, you could try a HashMap with a key for each question and a list of radio buttons per key. Then from here you could append to a new list the values clicked and stored.